# plone.caching Intercepted errors for all 304s

Tags: plone

I've recently started adding plone.caching ruleset declarations to my views:

```
<cache:ruleset
    for=".views.MyContentTypeView"
    ruleset="plone.content.itemView"
    />
```

I've started seeing these in my development site's log:

```
2012-10-23 14:48:02 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1351000082.330.867850813917 http://localhost:12311/my_content_type/@@landing
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 117, in publish
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module plone.caching.hooks, line 102, in intercept
Intercepted
```

From hooks.py, in intercept()'s docstring:

```
To properly abort request processing, this will raise an exception. The
actual response (typically an empty response) is then set via a view on
the exception. We set and lock the response status to avoid defaulting to
a 404 exception.
```

It therefore looks like these errors might be expected behaviour? If so, is it possible to get Zope to ignore these errors so they don't clutter my logs?

Comment: Intercepted should get added to the list of ignored exception types in error_log upon install of plone.app.caching. Perhaps that's not happening?

Comment: I think raising exception (HTTP 304) is the only way to make ZPublisher to stop traversing where is it now and immediately jump to creating 304 response. Basically it's an optimization. My guess.

Comment: Both of these comments agree with the premise that this is expected. I'll look at what's in my ignored exception types.

Comment: Intercepted wasn't in my ignored exception types -- I've been using p.a.caching since the betas, so perhaps it wasn't added during my initial install.